# Jest encountered an unexpected token. Jest failed to parse a file

Tags: next.js, jestjs, ts-jest, app-router

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

```
Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
```

i am trying to write test cases in nextjs(typescript) 13.4 App router using jest,ts-jest, RTL

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest')


const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const customJestConfig = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  // if using TypeScript with a baseUrl set to the root directory then you need the below for alias' to work
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I am able to understand you can try these steps:

The issue is jest does not parse `es6` import/export statement.

try configuring these files:

1. `jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
};
```

2. Add `babel.config`

[Here](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel) is how to do it

Hope this helps :)

Comment: not working bro